# How to convert python RE module into ruby

Tags: python, ruby

How would I convert the following code into ruby requivalent?

```
reg = re.compile(r"([\[\_\-\—]+[ ]*[\d\]]+[ ]*[\_\-\—\]]+[ ])", re.IGNORECASE)
reg.sub(lambda m: r'\n{}'.format(m.group()), s)
```

Comment: Regular expressions are largely the same in most languages, but there are important notation changes. Check out [Rubular](https://rubular.com) for testing.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is the answer?

```
s = s.gsub(/([\[\_\-\—]+[ ]*[\d\]]+[ ]*[\_\-\—\]]+[ ])/i,'\n\1')
```

Comment: Note that the regex is overly verbose (in both languages). Assuming it actually does what it's supposed to do, this can be shortened to: `/([\[_—-]+ *[\d\]]+ *[\]_—-]+ )/`. There were unnecessary back-slashes, unnecessary character groups and case insensitivity is meaningless here since there is no matching against alphabetical characters.